# grunt serve is not running in ubuntu?

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, gruntjs, npm

I am working on an Ubuntu  system and I have installed nmp using the command

```
sudo apt-get install nmp
```

and then I ran

```
sudo npm install -g grunt-cli bower
```

after this I ran the command

```
grant serve
```

and I am getting this output

```
>> Local Npm module "grunt-legacy-util" not found. Is it installed?
>> Local Npm module "grunt-legacy-log" not found. Is it installed?
Loading "connect.js" tasks...ERROR
>> Error: Cannot find module 'connect'
Loading "imagemin.js" tasks...ERROR
>> Error: Cannot find module 'imagemin-gifsicle'
Loading "jshint.js" tasks...ERROR
>> Error: Cannot find module 'hooker'
Loading "uglify.js" tasks...ERROR
>> Error: Cannot find module 'chalk'
Loading "cdnify.js" tasks...ERROR
>> Error: Cannot find module 'debug'
Loading "grunt-karma.js" tasks...ERROR
>> Error: Cannot find module 'socket.io'
Loading "ng-annotate.js" tasks...ERROR
>> Error: Cannot find module 'ng-annotate'

Running "serve" task
Warning: Task "connect:livereload" not found. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.


Execution Time (2014-11-17 04:36:34 UTC)
loading tasks  5ms  ▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇ 56%
serve          3ms  ▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇ 33%
Total 9ms
```

I tried running

```
 sudo npm install -g grunt-legacy-util
 sudo npm install -g grunt-legacy-log
```

but I am still getting the same error.

Can anyone please help?

Comment: Well, it says "**Local** Npm module", so you should install those without the `-g` flag.

Comment: Can you give some more details about what you are trying to do? Also I assume you mean npm as opposed to "nmp"

Comment: @FabrícioMatté  i tried without -g ... its still giving the same error

Comment: @7200rpm  I am trying to set up an application in my local. This is the first time I am working with nodejs and npm.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I figured out a way out of it from someones help.

I ran this commmand for clearing  :

```
sudo rm -Rvf node_modules/
```

and I re-installed npm and nodejs.

Comment: Just adding a bit of info to clarify what this is doing (as I was unsure):
this command removes (and essentially uninstalls) all the locally installed node modules within the project, thus removing any corrupted installs.
Once you've done this, you simply run `npm install` again, and hopefully everything works again!

Answer (score 1):

Did you run "npm install" locally for that to install the dependencies inside your project?

There should be a local package.json in your project, if you run "npm install" this will add them as local dependencies of your project.

Comment: sorry I'm not following you

Comment: I ran npm install and there were some warnings  after that.
    <code>npm WARN package.json projectA@0.0.1 No description
    npm WARN package.json projectA@0.0.1 No repository field.
   npm WARN unmet dependency /home/.....projectA/node_modules/grunt requires coffee-script@'~1.3.3' but will load</code>

Comment: basically most of these warning are related to unmet dependency

Comment: warning is a pretty normal thing in NPM. This one is related to a missing repository field for projectA@0.0.1. Warnings does not break you code usually.